# Generics where T is class implementing interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compact-framework

I have a interface:

```
interface IProfile { ... }
```

...and a class:

```
[Serializable]
class Profile : IProfile 
{ 
  private Profile()
  { ... } //private to ensure only xmlserializer creates instances
}
```

...and a manager with method:

```
class ProfileManager
{
  public T Load<T>(string profileName) where T : class, IProfile
  {
    using(var stream = new .......)
    {
      var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
      return (T)ser.Deserialize(stream);
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the method to be used like this:

```
var profile = myManager.Load<Profile>("TestProfile"); // class implementing IProfile as T
```

...and throw compile time error on this:

```
var profile = myManager.Load<IProfile>("TestProfile"); // NO! IProfile interface entered!
```

However everything compiles, and only runtime errors is thrown by the `XmlSerializer`.

I thought the `where T : class` would ensure only class types where accepted?

Is it possible to make the compiler throw error if `IProfile` (or other interfaces inheriting from `IProfile`) is entered, and only types classes implementing `IProfile` are accepted?

Comment: what error is thrown by `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: @Default that doesn't matter. The issue here is that `T` can be an interface, even though there's a `class` constraint.

Comment: @Default: InvalidOperationException{"IProfile cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor"}

Answer (score 42, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) class means that T must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

One work around would be to require that T implements the parameter less constructor so:

```
where T : class, IProfile, new()
```

Comment: Yes i thought of that, except C# wants the constructor to be public. :(

Comment: @Nautious The only other way may be to use code contracts

Comment: Perhaps another possibility is to create an abstract base class and set the constraint to the base class instead of the interface?

Comment: That won't work, because Load<AbstractBase>(...) would still compile and throw an exception at runtime. Using new() is the best way around this.

Comment: @zmbq Ah yes, I didn't really think it through.

Comment: @BobVale - I'm on .Net 3.5 CF, so Contracts are not available. I think i must bite the bullet and use the 'new()'

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
public interface IUser
{
    int AthleteId { get; set; }
    string GivenName { get; set; }
    string FamilyName { get; set; }         
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public  class DjsNameAutoSearch<Result, User> : where User : class, IUser, new()
```