# How can I require a generic type to have a class method in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, generic-programming

Let's say that I'm building a generic `Table<T>` class. Here are my requirements for the container:

- Type `T` must be a reference (or nullable, whichever you prefer) type, in order to use `null` in place of `T`. This gives me the `where T: class` constraint.
- Type `T` must be `IComparable`, since I want to compare the values in the table, which gives me another constraint of `where T : IComparable`. (There could be more interface constraints.)
- The generic type must be able to specialize to an interface, which means I can't further restrict this to inherit from some specific (even abstract) class.

In summary, the table would be defined as `class Table<T> where T: class, IComparable`. I also need to **create an instance of T which represents a *default* value**. The *default* doesn't necessarily mean just a default, there could be *two different default values*, just think of this as *creating some representative predefined values for the given type T* (this could also be something like max/min value.)

To reiterate my last point, I'd like to be able to use this to store types which don't share a common parent. For example, consider the following type hierarchy

```
         A
       / | \
      B  C  D
```

Now let's say that I only want to store types `B` and `C`, and nothing else. The ad-hoc solution would be to change the class hierarchy to look like this

```
         A
       /  \
      E    D 
     / \
    B   C
```

and now you could say that I can use `Table<E>`. But what if the classes `B` and `C` are completely unrelated? Or maybe they are already in an inheritance hierarchy of their own, and just share a common fact that they need to be stored in this table.

#### Possible solution but not ideal

The solution to this problem would be to define an interface that they would both implement, and use that as the generic type specialization. For example

```
class A {}
class B : A, IStorable {}
class C : A, IStorable {}
class D : A {}

interface IStorable {}
```

With this interface, I can now easily do `Table<IStorable>` and be sure that only the `B` and `C` types are being stored in the table, which is great. But this is where I got stuck. Using the interface, I no longer have a way to say *the type stored in the table should be able to create a default value*. In this particular case, it could be that the default value for `IStorable` is `new B(42)`, but I have no way of expressing that in the generic `Table<T>`, since it knows nothing about my type `T`. If I could say that `T` has to implement a static method, that could be used as a factory method, that would solve the problem, but **static methods can't be placed in an interface in C#**, so that is out of question as well.

The only workaround I found so far, is that the `Table<T>` has a constructor accepting `Func<T>`, which would be a function that can create the default value, but this feels very ad-hoc as well. Just to make it clear how that would look like

```
class Table<T> where T: class, IComparable, IStorable {
    Table(Func<T> factory) { ... }
}
```

**Is there a better way of using generic, such that I can create instances of the type `T`, while also allowing `T` to be an interface?** Just a disclaimer, the `default` operator is not good enough, since it only returns `null` for reference types, and requiring a parameterless constructor via `where T : new()` is not good enough as well, since that doesn't allow me to specialize `Table<T>` on an interface type.

Comment: Perhaps by taking two parameters? e.g. `Table<TItem, TFactory> where TItem : class, IComparable, IStorable where TFactory : IItemFactory<TItem>, new()`

Comment: Yeah, but that is basically the same as taking `Func<T>`, and more verbose :(

Comment: True, but a little less 'ad-hoc' to my eye.

Comment: i think you got your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247573/generics-where-t-is-class-implementing-interface

Comment: @yackovmandeszaig not raelly, I mentioned in the question that I can't use the default constructor in this case

Comment: The alternative to pretty standard "factory" parameter could be to try use expression trees to define access to "special value" - similar to how [Moq does it](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) if you can come up with nice syntax and are good with the trees. (Also I'd stick with factory method, possibly implemented with named instances resolved by DI container)

Comment: [Related VB.NET question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376890/how-to-get-classes-to-expose-the-same-shared-static-method)